# Java - java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host: connect

Tags: java, if-statement, connection

I have a class that returns a data string from a URL if there is a connection, if not it returns null.

My issue is that I am doing a check:

```
if (str == null) {
   System.out.println("Error: No Connection");
}
```

However, although this DOES works, this is also printed in the console:

```
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host: connect
```

I'm wondering what this means and if it implies I've made an error? Although the program works fine, other this this little exception that keeps popping up. Help?

Comment: I think Java is trying to establish a TCP session, but all packets are thrown out of the window by the network, hence the exception. Are you sure that you don't print it to the console yourself (e.g. using printStackTrace or similar)?

Comment: Two options I can think of: either there's a firewall or something blocks the port on the server you're trying to reach, or, you opened too many connections (sockets) without closing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete guess until you post more code... but my guess is you forgot to return after you print your message return str, if not its going to try to execute the rest of your code..

```
private String myFunction(String url){
    if (str == null) {
       System.out.println("Error: No Connection");
       return null;
    }
    //do other stuff that you are already doing .

}
```